# Norton's Settings Are Affecting My Linksys Wireless Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, uninstall, norton-removal-tool

After Norton expired on my new pc, my Linksys wireless router stopped sending wifi. Hard wired PCs can still connect, but wireless devices cannot. The WLAN light won't even come on anymore! I tried using Norton Removal Tool but, that didn't fix it.

How can I remove Norton's setting for my wireless-router/network so that I can connect to my network over wifi?

Comment: How do you know Norton changed the settings on your router?

Comment: Check your Linksys settings manually by viewing the router's management page in your browser. This is usually something like `http://192.168.0.1`,  `http://192.168.1.1`, or `http://192.168.2.1` (consult the manual).

Comment: P.S. You'll need to have a cabled connection to connect to the router to access the administration settings.

Comment: Another reason Not to use Norton products. Most likely the problem is with the PC and not the router. Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the reset button on the router to restore its default settings and start from scratch. That way you will know it is done correctly. Resetting the router restores the router to its origanal factory fresh in the box settings.

Answer (score 0):

Norton can't change a router settings. Just reboot your router or alter the wifi channel.